# Network traffic analyzer for Video

Tags: network, network-scanners

I am going to be streaming video on an open network. I need the simplest network traffic analyzer that would enable me to know when the video is stopped and started from another system on the same network.

Comment: How is this security related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to use WireShark and setup filter colors for video encoding streams. This way you only have to look at the colors of the current traffic to see the video.

You could also colorize your ip traffic in green and video streams from other IP's in another color such as red.

Note: there are several other ways to do this in WireShark.

https://www.wireshark.org